# Equivalent of GetApplicationScript() on Mac 64 bit

Tags: macos, internationalization, 64-bit

I use GetApplicationScript() function to determine the current script on Mac 32 bit. But this function is not available on 64 bit. Please suggest its equivalent on Mac 64 bit

Comment: What do you plan to do with the script code if you can get it?  Are there any APIs that take a script code that are available in 64 bits?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [`CFLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/Reference/reference.html) and its `CFLocaleGetSystem` function call.

This returns the locale of the system (not the application) and from that, you can do `CFLocaleGetValue` using a key of `kCFLocaleScriptCode`.

That should give you what you want.